# Product_Order verifyOrder API fails when adding guest_disks

Tags: c#, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have a C# application in which I imported API methods using wsdl, as described in the Softlayer guidelines.
I'm editing virtual guests by passing a Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade structure to the Product_Order service.

Everything works great except for when adding item price IDs for guest_disks, scenario in which after about 6-7 seconds the following exception is thrown: 
"The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
This happens with both verifyOrder and placeOrder methods.

I checked Virtual_Guest::getUpgradeItemPrices in order to make sure that the guest disk values are valid(even though passing invalid itempriceIds for the VM results in an specific error response, not in a generic exception such as the one described above).

I can't find any details in the documentation that could give me hints as why I can upgrade anything except guest_disks.

EDIT:
Stripped code as requested:

```
            SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest[] _VMtoEditList = new SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest[1] { -- Vm instance details are retrieved from SL according to the passed VM ID; };

            List<SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price> _itemPriceList = new List<SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price>();

            foreach (-- collection of properties to be upgraded )
            {
                SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category _category = new SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category();
                _category.categoryCode = -- retrieved from the collection on which I iterate (eg "guest_disk0", "ram", etc.);


                SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price _itemPrice = new SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price();
                _itemPrice.id = -- the item priceID for the current item;
                _itemPrice.idSpecified = true;
                _itemPrice.categories = new SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category[1] { _category };

                _itemPriceList.Add(_itemPrice);
            }
            SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price[] _itemPricesArray = _itemPriceList.ToArray();

            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property _property1 = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property();
            _property1.name = "NOTE_GENERAL";
            _property1.value = -- order's description;

            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property _property2 = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property();
            _property2.name = "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW";
            _property2.value = "now";

            // Build SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property
            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property[] properties = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property[2] { _property1, _property2 };

            -- create container
            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade _upgradeContainer = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade();
            _upgradeContainer.virtualGuests = _VMtoEditList;
            _upgradeContainer.prices = _itemPricesArray;
            _upgradeContainer.properties = properties;
            _upgradeContainer.packageId = 46;
            _upgradeContainer.packageIdSpecified = true;

            SoftLayer_Product_OrderService service = new SoftLayer_Product_OrderService();
            -- authentication structure is created here

            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order _verifiedOrder = service.verifyOrder(_upgradeContainer);
            service.placeOrder(_verifiedOrder, false);
```

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here a have an example to upgrade which works see below. I see that in your code you are adding the packageId which is not required, removed and try again.

Also when you are creating the web references try using the last version of the api in the WSDL url (v3.1) 
e.g. https://api.softlayer.com/soap/v3.1/SoftLayer_Hardware_Server?wsdl

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="PlaceOrderUpgrade.cs" company="Softlayer">
//     SoftLayer Technologies, Inc.
// </copyright>
// <license>
// http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
// </license>
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
namespace VirtualGuests
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    class PlaceOrderUpgrade
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Order an upgrade for Virtual Guest
        ///  This script orders an upgrade for Virtual Guest, in this case we will upgrade the ram for a Virtual Guest,
        ///  It uses SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade container and SoftLayer_Product_Order::placeOrder
        ///  method for it.
        ///  For more information, review the following links:
        /// </summary>
        /// <manualPages>
        /// http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder
        /// http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade/
        /// http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price/
        /// </manualPages>
        static void Main(String [] args)
        {
            // You SoftLayer username
            string username = "set me";
            // Your SoftLayer API key.            
            string apiKey = "set me";
            // Define the virtual guest id to place an upgrade
            int virtualId = 13115425;
            // Creating a connection to the SoftLayer_Product_Order API service and             
            // bind our API username and key to it.           
            authenticate authenticate = new authenticate();
            authenticate.username = username;
            authenticate.apiKey = apiKey;

            SoftLayer_Product_OrderService orderService = new SoftLayer_Product_OrderService();
            orderService.authenticateValue = authenticate;
            // Build a SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects with the ids from prices that you want to order. 
            // You can retrieve them with SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices method
            int[] prices = {
                                1645
                            };
            List<SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price> pricesList = new List<SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price>();
            foreach (var price in prices)
            {
                SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price newPrice = new SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price();
                newPrice.id = price;
                newPrice.idSpecified = true;
                pricesList.Add(newPrice);
            }

            // Build SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property object for the upgrade
            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property property = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property();
            property.name = "MAINTENANCE_WINDOW";
            property.value = "NOW";

            List<SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property> propertyList = new List<SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Property>();
            propertyList.Add(property);

            // Build SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest object with the id from vsi that you wish to place an upgrade
            SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest virtualGuest = new SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest();
            virtualGuest.id = virtualId;
            virtualGuest.idSpecified = true;

            List<SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest> virtualGuests = new List<SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest>();
            virtualGuests.Add(virtualGuest);

            // Build SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object containing the information for the upgrade
            //SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order orderTemplate = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order();
            SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade orderTemplate = new SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade();
            orderTemplate.containerIdentifier = "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest_Upgrade";
            orderTemplate.prices = pricesList.ToArray();
            orderTemplate.properties = propertyList.ToArray();
            orderTemplate.virtualGuests = virtualGuests.ToArray();
            try
            {
                // We will check the template for errors, we will use the verifyOrder() method for this. 
                // Replace it with placeOrder() method when you are ready to order.
                SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order verifiedOrder = orderService.verifyOrder(orderTemplate);
                Console.WriteLine("Order Verified!");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to place an upgrade for Virtual Guest: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps

Regards

Comment: Removing the PackageId has no effect. Except for that as far as I can tell, there's no difference between your example and my code(only the missing itemprice categorycode, which in my case could could be an issue in scenarios which contain 2 or more block devices that have the same itempriceId). I will try re-importing the SoftLayer APIs tomorrow, in order to contain v. 3.1 as you suggested.